# What's the difference between a set and a mapping to boolean?

Tags: scala, dictionary, set

In Scala, I sometimes use a Map[A, Boolean], sometimes a Set[A].  There's really not much difference between these two concepts, and an implementation might use the same data structure to implement them.  So why bother to have Sets?  As I said, this question occurred to me in connection with Scala, but it would arise in any programming language whose library implements a Set abstraction.

Comment: One difference occurs to me: Map[A, Boolean] can represent three values for get(x): true, false, and no entry, which might mean "yes," "no," and "unknown."  Set[A] can represent only two.  But this difference makes the Set abstraction seem even more redundant.

Comment: maybe `Map[A, Unit]` would express `Set` better

Answer (score 2):

The are some specific convenient methods defined on [Set](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Set.html) (intersect, diff and more). Not a big deal, but often useful.

Answer (score 2):

My first thoughts are two:

1. **efficiency**: if you only want to signal presence, why bothering with a flag that can either be true or false?
2. **meaning**: a set is about the existence of something, a map is about a correlation between a key and value (generally speaking); these two ideas are quite different and should be used accordingly to simplify reading and understanding the code

Furthermore, the semantics of application change:

```
val map: Map[String, Bool] = Map("hello" -> true, "world" -> false)
val set: Set[String] = Set("hello")

map("hello") // true
map("world") // false
map("none!") // EXCEPTION

set("hello") // true
set("world") // false
set("none!") // false
```

Without having to actually store an extra pair to indicate absence (not to mention the boolean that actually indicates such absence).

Sets are very good to indicate the presence of something, which makes them very good for filtering:

```
val map = (0 until 10).map(_.toString).zipWithIndex.toMap
val set = (3 to 5).map(_.toString).toSet
map.filterKeys(set) // keeps pairs 3rd through 5th
```

Maps, in terms of processing collections, are good to indicate relationships, which makes them very good for collecting:

```
set.collect(map) // more or less equivalent as above, but only values are returned
```

You can read more about using collections as functions to process other collections [here](http://www.alessandrolacava.com/blog/scala-seq-map-and-set-as-functions/).

Comment: Thanks.  You could say that Set[A] is a convenient type to use instead of Map[A, Boolean] with a default value of false.

Answer (score 1):

There are several reasons:

1) It is easier to think/work with a data structure that only has single elements as opposed to mapping to dummy `true`,

For example, it is easier to convert a list to `Set`, then to `Map`:

```
scala> val myList = List(1,2,3,2,1)
myList: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 2, 1)

scala> myList.toSet
res9: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(1, 2, 3)

scala> myList.map(x => (x, true)).toMap
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Boolean] = Map(1 -> true, 2 -> true, 3 -> true)
```

2) As Kombajn zbożowy pointed out, Sets have additional helper methods, `union`, `intersect`, `diff`, `subsetOf`.

3) Sense `Set` does not have mapping to dummy variable the size of a set in memory is smaller, this is more noticeable for small sized keys.

Having said the above, not all languages have `Set` data structure, `Go` for example does not.

Comment: The conversion `Map` could be written better: `myList.map(x => (x, true)).toMap`. Agreed on other points.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov, That certainly is better. I changed my answer to reflect your suggestion. Thank You.